# Finding the column index for the first numeric or date column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA coding and I want to find the column index for the ****first** numeric / short date / date column** in a worksheet.

An example of what the data looks like this:

```
id     sex     2015   2016
2       M       1       3
4       F       7       5
3       F       8       9
```

In this example, the answer should be 3. I'd like to set this as a variable so I can use this number later.

This is my code so far:

```
Sub find_value()

Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A500") 
    Set c = .Find(2015, lookin:=xlValues) 

End Sub
```

As you can see, this is just a static solution.

Any ideas would be great! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very rough, but here is a function that would get you the result you are after. You can call on `result` for later use or call the function as you need.
This is purposefully broken out so you can see how `find_value` becomes defined. You could amalgamate the code if you choose.

```
Sub test()
    Dim result As String
    result = find_value(2015, 1) 'find year 2015, entry 1
    
    Debug.Print result
    
End Sub

Function find_value(year As Integer, entry As Integer)
    Dim yearVal, entryVal, foundVal As Integer
    yearVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(year, Worksheets(1).Range("1:1"), 0)
    entryVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(entry, Worksheets(1).Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, yearVal), Worksheets(1).Cells(500, yearVal)), 0)
    foundVal = Cells(entryVal, yearVal + 1)
    find_value = foundVal
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks :) I can see the logic for using the match function, but I get an error "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class". Any thoughts?

Comment: No problem. It could be related to not specifying the workbook throughout the code. Anything that references `Worksheets()` and `Cells()` should be accompanied by a `Workbook()`. This way, if the workbook changes (swapping from one to another as an example), the code will always be directed to the reference you are looking for.